# Sample code for implementation of HAL(Hypermedia Application Language) specification

Tags: spring-boot, maven-3, spring-hateoas

Will somebody please post Sample code for implementation of HAL(Hypermedia Application Language) specification using Spring HATEOAS in maven which contains links and resources.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the samples from Oliver Gierke (Spring Hateoas project lead):

> Small sample: https://github.com/olivergierke/spring-hateoas-sample
>
> Big sample: https://github.com/olivergierke/spring-restbucks

Cheers,

Andreas

Comment: If you found the reply useful, maybe mark it as solution. Makes it clearer for others.

Comment: above links are found to be really useful. if anyone wants some other reference then following link is also useful.                                                                   http://blog.zenika.com/index.php?post/2012/06/13/HATEOAS-with-Spring-MVC-REST                                                                                                     for source code see the following link                                                       https://github.com/acogoluegnes/hateoas